# Help with some calculations

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

My question is: what I need to do to get 2nd equation from the first?

1)

$TP1 = vp1 · λ + TS1$
$TP2 = vp2 · λ + TS2$

2)$$TP_2 − TS_2 =\frac{vp2}{vp1}(TP1 − TS1)$$

Comment: From first equation you have $\lambda=\frac{TP_1-TS_1}{vp_1}$. set it in second equation and you get the required.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at the two equations, which terms are missing when you go from 1) to 2). Try to eliminate that term.

Comment: i solved it, thanks =). Im weak at my math, because I didnt used for more than 5 years!